# No errors shown/logged beyond shell script

Tags: magento-1.9, error, mage-shell

I have a strange issue where no errors are shown or logged if it occurs beyond the shell script. I have a Magento shell script (`... extends Mage_Shell_Abstract`), which serves as an entry point for a module that does some backend stuff (update database records, etc.).

The problem is that, while syntax, fatal, parse, etc. errors are displayed if they're from the shell script itself, no errors are shown or logged in the terminal if they arise from the module files.

I have all the options enabled for logging and displaying errors, but errors are not showing, and it's really hard to debug. I have enabled..

```
// At the beginning of the shell script
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('error_reporting', 'On');

// php.ini
error_reporting  =  E_ALL|E_STRICT
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up including `error_reporting(E_ALL)` again in the shell script, even though it's set in `php.ini`. That makes all errors to be reported from all files. This fixes the issue where only the shell script was reporting errors.